# Is there any need of antivirous program such as microsoft windows?

Tags: security, antivirus

Microsoft windows needs an anti virus program to protect system from virus and other programs which are harmful for the system. Is there any need of such type program for Ubuntu OS? If not then why?

Comment: Depends, Linux is not windows, so a better question is what you want to use antivirus for. Scanning a typical desktop -> not much use. Scanning a shared flash drive, shared samba directory, mail sever, perhaps, but really IMO best off running av on windows if you use windows and for the most part no needed on Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few antivirus programs for Ubuntu. But most likely you won't need any. I will explain why:

- You should ALWAYS get software from the official repositories (the ones available in the Software Center). Every single piece of software available there is completely virus free. If you only get packages from the official sources you will be safe;
- There are very few viruses for Linux. This happens because most of the virus production has Windows as a target;
- Everything that requires important changes in Ubuntu needs root privileges. You must have root access to do these changes. Nothing important will be changed unless you give your password (that's why you should always be careful about commands starting with 'sudo' or 'su').

So...

Probably you shouldn't worry about getting an antivirus. If you follow all the security rules you won't be affected.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can install clamav》 
"sudo apt-get install clamav"
However in linux it is not necessarily necessary. I would read the link posted above.